# Force position of full page sized figure

Tags: floats, positioning

I'd like to have text that is placed after a figure **which occupies a whole page** also to be placed after that page in the produces PDF file.

Imagine this (pseudo latex, not necessarily a working example):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\section{ONE}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet 

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  % some figure that takes the whole next page
\end{figure}

\section{TWO}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet 
\end{document}
```

This results in a pdf document which looks kind of like this:

```
ONE
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet 

TWO
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet 
---- page break ----

[FIGURE]

---- page break ----
```

So, how do I get the figure to be placed at the end of section{one} and before section{two} where it is supposed to be instead of slipping into section{two}? Even if that means that section{one} only takes a fraction of page. Isn't that what [!htbp] actually is for?

**//edit** Regarding [this](http://tex.lickert.net/tipps/optionh/optionh.html) text (in German, unfortunately; I hope you'll understand it anyway, in case of necessity, using Google Translator) in some cases it's just not a good idea to use floats. What do you think about it?

Comment: As Section two should began on a new page insert `\clearpage` before `\section{Section Two}`. Macro `\clearpage` forces that first are all missing images printed, thenn follows Section 2 .

Comment: I just want to make sure the figure is exactly where I want it to be. For this purpose [H], as mentioned by vonbrand, serves me well.

Answer (score 13):

Combine the option `[p]` (page float) with `\afterpage`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for the example

\begin{document}
\section{ONE}
\lipsum[1]

\afterpage{\clearpage}
\begin{figure}[p] % <--- only p
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{6cm}\rule{6cm}{0pt}}
\caption{Some figure that takes the whole next page}
\label{nextpage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

The `\afterpage{\clearpage}` command will issue a `\clearpage` as soon as the next page is completed and `\clearpage` flushes the float queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use package `float`, you have the extra option `H`, which means "place the float **HERE**".